# How to use Microsoft Graph Toolkit with SPFX 1.15.2

Tags: spfx, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I created a new SPFX solution with yo. Then I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/build-a-sharepoint-web-part) guide:

Installed with

```
npm install @microsoft/mgt-spfx
```

and

```
npm install @microsoft/mgt-react
```

Then I changed the init method in the webpart.ts file to following code

```
protected onInit(): Promise<void> {

    if (!Providers.globalProvider) {
      Providers.globalProvider = new SharePointProvider(this.context);
    }

    return super.onInit();
}
```

Added the import

```
import { SharePointProvider, Providers } from '@microsoft/mgt-spfx';
```

In the tsx component file I changed the render to

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IPeoplePickerTestProps> {

    return (
      <div>
        Test
        <Person personQuery="me" view={ViewType.image}></Person>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

and added the import

```
import { Person, ViewType } from '@microsoft/mgt-react/dist/es6';
```

Then I uploaded the latest toolkit spfx package ([got it here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/releases/tag/v2.6.1)) to the app catalog (deployed to all sites), builded my solution (gulp bundle --ship, gulp package-solution --ship) and uploaded it to the app catalog. Created a new site collection and installed my solution. Its not working at all. There is nothing rendered except the text "Test". In the console I can see following error which does not really help me:
[image: error message showing in edge debugger console: Could not load people-picker-test-web-part in require. Trying in system.js. DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "mgt-mock-provider" has already been used with this registry]

Toolkit version: 2.6.1
SPFX version: 1.15.2

Tested on different tenants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got similar issue, try importing from
@microsoft/mgt-react/dist/es6/spfx

so:

```
import { Person } from '@microsoft/mgt-react/dist/es6/spfx';
import { ViewType } from '@microsoft/mgt-spfx';
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Ok almost yes. I tried that but ViewType is not part of the spfx. I changed the ViewType import to @microsoft/mgt-spfx. Now its working. If you can change that in your answer I can accept it ;)